# Redirect to different Actions in symfony2 having same url

Tags: rest, symfony

I want create API which has same URL say `http://stackoverflow.com/profile` but having different request method like `POST`, `PUT`, `GET`, etc. I want to do different action based on method type. One way is write common action which for comparing methods and redirect using

```
$this->forward('anotherModule','anotherAction');
```

Is there any other way to check it's method and redirect to different actions without using one general action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `routing.yml` you can define different controllers for the same pattern based on request method

```
read:
    pattern: /yourUrl
    defaults: { _controller: your.controller:readAction }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

write:
    pattern: /yourUrl
    defaults: { _controller: your.controller:writeAction }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

Or if you use annotations:

```
/**
 * @Route("/yourRoute", requirements={"_method" = "GET"})
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    ...
}

/**
 * @Route("/yourRoute", requirements={"_method" = "POST"})
 */
public function writeAction($id)
{
    ...
}
```